# Split multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas, where I want to remove everything after a specific charater.

I have used the split function so far, which works on 1 column.

```
df3['defending_marking'] = df3['defending_marking'].apply(lambda x: x.split('+')[0])
```

I want to do that on all columns with fx. iloc

```
df3.iloc[:,:] = df3.iloc[:,:].apply(lambda x: x.split('+')[0])
```

I just get an error.

Could you help ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 1st one, you use `Series.apply` where `x` is each string of the series/column. `split` got applied directly on each string, so it works fine. On the 2nd one, you use `dataframe.apply` where `x` is each column(i.e. series) of dataframe. Now, `split` got applied on each series, so it fails.

On 2n one, you need call `str.split` as follows

```
df3 = df3.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('+').str[0])
```

As you use `split` to pick only first part, adding option `n=1` to stop the split after first found would make the code run faster

```
df3 = df3.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('+', n=1).str[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! But it seems like it runs the code, but then remove all rows except 1, in all the columns? :/

Comment: Sorry! I should have mentioned the dataset have 29 columns with 18000 rows

Comment: @KasperHøxbroeJeppesen: I forgot the `.str[0]`. I fixed it. Check my edited answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass [:,:]. You should use axis = 1 in the apply function to pass each column one by one to the lambda function and then reassign back to the same data frame.

```
df3 = df3.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('+')[0], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Interesting. How would you put that into the code ? I cant quite figure out where you would put it ?

Comment: df3 = df3.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('+')[0], axis = 1)

Comment: Thank you! But when I try to use it, it applies to only 1 column and leave out the rest of the columns ? - Sorry! I should have mentioned the dataset have 29 columns with 18000 rows